# Can a solvable problem be encoded in a recursively enumerable language?

Tags: turing-machines, decision-problem

Imagine I have a turing machine that can decide on a specific problem using a language. My question is that that problem (that can be decided by a TM M, with language L) can be encoded in a new language that is recursive enumerable.

If yes, this would mean that every solvable problem can encoded in recursive language; if not, a problem can be encoded in a recursive and/or recursive enumerable L and the problem could become semi-decidable for a different language.

Any clarification on this?

Comment: I'm not sure you understand the meaning of (decision) *problem* and *language* in this context. They have the same meaning. A *decision problem* or *language* is a subset of $\Sigma^*$. That's the definition.

Comment: Well, if I have a connected graph decision problem, then I will have to translate the decision problem with an encoding scheme into a language. This question is concerned whether I may encode a solvable problem in a recursevely enumerable language

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost immediately from [definitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_problem), one has:

- A solvable (decidable) problem can be encoded as (not in) a recursive language.
- A semi-decidable problem can be encoded as (not in) a recursively enumerable language.